# OpenShift docker push 500 internal server error

Tags: docker, openshift, docker-registry, openshift-client-tools, okd

I am running OpenShift 3.11 version and followed instructions from this documentation: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/registry/accessing_registry.html

However, whenever I run the below command, I see the error:

```
docker push 172.30.<num>.<num>:5000/project/image
received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

I also checked the output of registry logs:

```
oc logs dc/docker-registry
```

It blurts out huge output but here is what caught my attention:

```
imagestreams.image.openshift.io <> is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:registry\" cannot get imagestreams.image.openshift.io in the namespace \"<>\": no RBAC policy matched"
```

Therefore, I am confused why I am getting this permission issue. As per the documentation, it should have worked and there should not be any need for image stream and I should be able to push docker images directly into the registry. Does anyone have an idea what I am missing here?

EDIT:

Below is the complete list commands for the entire setup:

```
oc cluster up <params>
Created a new project as a test setup and that works.
htpasswd -c /etc/origin/openshift-htpasswd <username> (I use the same <username> by using which I created the project above.)
oc login -u <username> -p <password>
oc policy add-role-to-user registry-editor <username>
oc adm registry
oc get svc/docker-registry (make note of cluster ip and port)
Modify or create /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "cluster ip:port" ]
}
systemctl restart docker
Restart cluster and login again using <username>
docker login -u nouser -p $(oc whoami -t) cluster ip:port
docker push cluster ip:port/project/image
This is where I see 500 internal server error.

Cluster ip has the format of 172.30.<num>.<num>:5000
```

EDIT 2:
When I create the registry using the below command, I get some errors that it already exists even though I delete it beforehand:

```
oc adm registry (for creating registry)
oc delete dc/docker-registry svc/docker-registry (for deleting registry)
```

[image]

I do delete them since I have been repeating these steps multiple times to figure out the cause of this issue. Do you think this output looks troublesome?

EDIT 3: More info from error message:

> findBlobStore: unable get access to imagestream myproject/busybox: ImageStream:Forbidden: Exists: failed to get image stream myproject/busybox: ImageStreamGetter:Forbidden: myproject/busybox: imagestreams.image.openshift.io \"busybox\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:myproject:registry\" cannot get imagestreams.image.openshift.io in the namespace \"myproject\": no RBAC policy matched"

Answer (score 0):

Did you login to internal `docker-registry` using correct account before `docker push` ? This account should have permission to push or create images on target `project` you specified "172.30..:5000/`project`/image".

```
$ oc login -u username -p password
$ oc whoami -t
...TOKEN...

$ docker login -u unused -p ...TOKEN... 172.30.<num>.<num>:5000
$ docker push 172.30.<num>.<num>:5000/project/image:tag
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. And the permissions to the <username> are: admin, registry-editor, system:image-builder, system:image-pusher.
Also, I assigned cluster-admin role to this user as well.

Comment: Hmm, it's odd. I can push images in my OCP through above steps I provided. Can you test whether other push tasks also have same issue using `oc new-app centos/ruby-25-centos7~https://github.com/sclorg/ruby-ex.git` ? If pushing build image also is failed, it may have issue on docker-registry pod.

Comment: I could run the above command with success. So that means docker-registry POD is good?

Comment: I updated the question with the complete list of commands. Do you think there is missing something?

Comment: Would you create target project using same account you login before push image to "cluster ip:port/project/image"  ? `oc new-project project`.

Comment: No, that didn't help. I get the same 500 internal server error :(

Comment: I also posted the output in my original posr under edit section when I create registry. Some components already exists even though I delete the registry. Do you think it might be related to the issue I am facing?